# Update two Treeview Tkinter which are in different class with only one button. python

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Hello guys I need some help with my GUI. I want to insert an item in one of the treeview and at the same time up date the other treeview and insert a number in an entry. The problem is that the first treeview is create in a different class from the second treeview and entry box. The below code is a short version from the current one. I appreciate the help and patience with new programmers like me. Thanks in advance.

```
class store(Page):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent=parent

        frame2 = tk.Frame(self, width=500, height=500, bd = 2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        frame2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        ### 
        self.label = tk.Label(frame2, text="Inventario", font="Helvetica 18 bold", justify="center")
        self.label.pack(side="top", pady=10, fill="x", anchor=tk.E)


        ### 
        frame_b=tk.Frame(frame2, bd = 2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        frame_b.pack(side="right", anchor=tk.N+tk.W)

        ##
        frame_in=tk.Frame(frame2, bd = 2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        frame_in.pack(side="right", anchor=tk.N+tk.W, padx=5)

        # 
        self.tree=ttk.Treeview(frame_in, columns=("Product", "Unitari Cost ($/Kg)", "Date"), height=20)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='#')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text="Product")
        self.tree.heading('#2', text="Unitari Cost ($/Kg)")
        self.tree.heading('#3', text="Date")
        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=0, width=50, anchor=tk.W)
        self.tree.column('#1', stretch=0, width=400, anchor=tk.N)
        self.tree.column('#2', stretch=0, width=200, anchor=tk.N)
        self.tree.column('#3', stretch=0, width=200, anchor=tk.N)
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)


        # 
        self.ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_in, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree['yscroll'] = self.ysb.set
        self.ysb.grid(in_=frame_in, row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)

        obj = general_production()

        # 
        def new_item():
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text= 1, values=("Bread", "2355.23", "12/02/2020"))
            obj.up_date_production()


        ## 
        b_new = tk.Button(frame_b, text="New", width = 10, command=new_item)
        b_new.pack(pady=5, padx= 5)


class general_production(Page):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent=parent

        frame2 = tk.Frame(self, width=500, height=500, bd = 2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        frame2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        ####
        label = tk.Label(frame2, text="Formulas", font="Helvetica 18 bold", justify="center")
        label.pack(side="top", pady=10, fill="x", anchor=tk.E)

        ### 
        frame_b=tk.Frame(frame2, bd = 2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        frame_b.pack(side="right", anchor=tk.N+tk.W)

        ### 
        frame_f=tk.Frame(frame2, bd = 2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        frame_f.pack(side="right", anchor=tk.N+tk.W, padx=5)

        ## 
        self.tree=ttk.Treeview(frame_f, columns=("#1", "#2"), height=20)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Product')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text="Unitari Cost ($/Kg)")
        self.tree.heading('#2', text="Production per day (Kg/day)")

        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=0, width=250)
        self.tree.column('#1', stretch=0, width=100, anchor=tk.N)
        self.tree.column('#2', stretch=0, width=150, anchor=tk.N)

        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        # 
        self.ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_f, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree['yscroll'] = self.ysb.set
        self.ysb.grid(in_=frame_f, row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)

        # 
        self.n_recipies =tk.StringVar()
        entrie =tk.Entry(frame2, width = 20, textvariable =self.n_recipies, state='readonly', readonlybackground ="white")
        entrie.pack(side="right", anchor=tk.N+tk.W)

        def up_date_production(self):
            self.treeview.insert("", "end", text= "Bread", values=("2355.23", "987"))
            self.n_recipies.set(1)
```

Comment: It would help if you removed all of the code that is not directly related to the question. For example, we don't care about multiple columns or headings or other widgets. It sounds like you're simply asking how to reference a tree in one class from another. For that we only need a couple classes and a couple of tree widgets.

Comment: Pick one from: [`[python] "variable from one class to another"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1+%5Bpython%5D+%22variable+from+one+class+to+another%22)